# Android NFC adapter scanning same tag twice

Tags: android, nfc

I've an app that uses NFC technology. I have client data stored on the tag which is made into a transaction and eventually sent to the server. The app seems to work fine if the user scans the tag correctly. For example, the user must place the tag on the table in front of them, then place the phone on top of the tag and leave until the transaction is sent.

What i've noticed is, if the phone is waved about above the tag then the NFC adapter seems to be triggered multiple times. I know that NFC works within a few cm and I understand this is user error. The implications this has on the overall system is quite serious. The app is for the home care industry and the extra transaction the phone is making can eventually knock a carer call off a client. This means it could be possible for a carer not to visit an elderly client(who may need medication).

Is it possible to make the adapter fire only once within a given tolerance, say 5 seconds?
I've noticed that the scan times of the tag from the false duplicate scans are millisecs apart. so in effect the adapter is reading the same tag milli-secs apart.

thanks in advance, Matt

NB. I've tried to handle this behaviour before I send the transaction to web services. I've written the scan time to a table on the phone, then every call to web services i check to see if the scan time is already there. if it is then i don't send it. This is a bit of a patch and ideally it would be better handled by the NFC adapter.

Comment: You are already handling this issue the right way. However I believe you cannot get multiple NFC events within a few milliseconds, so that must be a bug (in your code?).

Comment: @Thomas i can prove the adapter is triggered multiple times. not every time but it has happened. also if you scan to quickly, only the tag ID is extracted and the adapter doesn't have enough time to read the payload. when this latter happens, a formatted tag with a payload is treated as formatted tag without a payload. this in the main system causes problems as some companies use unformatted tags, so the tagId is used to match a carer, where a formatted tag has the carer id in the payload.

Comment: You would be able to distinguish between tag id only and tag id + payload scenarios, so what is the real problem? You must indicate to the user whether scanning was successful?

Comment: @Thomas yes i trap for NdefDiscovered and TechDiscovered. What i'm trying to say is if the user scans the tag in the correct manner, there are no problems. This is true of unformatted tags without a payload or formatted tags with a payload. The company i work for had 2 previous apps written in j2me. these worked on a Nokia c700 phone. All the tags in the clients homes were unformatted tags straight off the roll. The nokias simply sent the tag ID to server where it got matched to the client's details in the main system. I've created an android app that does the same but can use formatted tags

Comment: if the the user scans a formatted tag incorrectly, the app doesn't send the payload only the id in some cases. So if only the tag id is sent it can't be matched in the main system for that carer, as the client and carer id were expected with the transaction not just the tagID. The hard part is that certain companies still just use the tagid so i can't just simply check if the payload is a certain length. The problem i'm having is the user is making 2 valid transactions off one scan. The user is thinking they have made one valid scan, but they are holding the phone just far enough away for the

Comment: adapter to trigger twice with millisec. I just thought there maybe something in the NFC api that turn the adapter off or disables it after a scan.